# Youtube Data API find similar videos

Tags: javascript, youtube, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I am using the Youtube Data API (v3) to find, load and display a video with all its information. However, I want to also **show other video suggestions** next to it. These should be **similar to the content** of the video that is currently being watched.

I thought that I could do that with the `topicId` or the `videoCategoryId` parameter of the search list. However, I don't know **how I can get the category or topic of the main video**. All possible information I can get is the following:

> - contentDetails
> - fileDetails
> - id
> - liveStreamingDetails
> - localizations
> - player
> - processingDetails
> - recordingDetails
> - snippet
> - statistics
> - status
> - suggestions
> - topicDetails
>
> [YouTube Data API Documentation](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/list#part)

**How can I get the topic of a video and then use it to find other ones that are similar?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are [`topicDetails`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos#topicDetails) and [`snippet.categoryId`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos#snippet.categoryId).

Note that directly using the filter [`relatedToVideoId`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search/list#relatedToVideoId) from the [YouTube Data API v3](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3) [Search: list](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search/list) endpoint would maybe make more sense.

**Update-**

The *search.list* method's [`relatedToVideoId`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search/list#relatedToVideoId) parameter has been deprecated from August 7, 2023 by YouTube.

https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/revision_history#june-12,-2023